# What are the various built-in modules of ODOO?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I couldn't find any reference to what various modules from OpenERP/ODOO v8, or ODOO in general, actually are.

For example, what does `res` or `ir` stand for? Does anyone have a complete list of these anywhere?